# How to pass List<int> in query string to a controller's action in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, collections, query-string

In C# I have three objects in my class like:

```
public class ABC{
public int AgeMin{get;set;}
public int AgeMax{get;set;}
public List<int> MaritalStatuses{get;set;}
}
```

Now when I pass all these objects values to controller's action via query string which is receiving the object of type ABC, I am passing like this:

```
&AgeMin=@Model.filter.AgeMin&AgeMax=@Model.filter.AgeMax&MaritalStatuses=@string.Join(",", @Model.filter.MaritalStatuses)
```

Values of AgeMin and AgeMax are correct but values of List MaritalStatuses are not correct because it is a List. How can I pass this List values to query string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change MaritalStatuses to MaritalStatuses[0], MaritalStatuses[1] etc

Answer (score 0):

Well cannot test it right now but you can have a better control if you write a function inside your model class to return proper query string or may be have a wrapper over model or even some extension method taking model object and returning query string for it. Like this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int AgeMin { get; set; }
    public int AgeMax { get; set; }
    public List<int> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }

    public string ToQueryString()
    {
        return string.Format("AgeMin={0}&AgeMax={1}&MaritialStatuses={2}", 
                            AgeMin, AgeMax, string.Join(",", MaritalStatuses));
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("someAction")?@(Model.ToQueryString())">Testing</a>
```